# How to make a JLabel clickable?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, mouseover, mouse-cursor

I want to customize a JLable to make him clickable, i'm not talking about adding an Action Listener because i already have, i'm talking about changing the mouse cursor's reaction when the JLabel gain Focus just like the reaction of a mouse hoover on a link in the browser.

[image]

I have impression that is not possible with swing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about:

```
label.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
```

Answer (score 6):

Swing APIs have a way of doing it:

```
label.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
```

and when you change your mind:

```
label.setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
```

Answer (score 5):

> I have impression that is not possible with swing.

Or maybe you just haven't yet learned how to do this perhaps? A MouseListener and MouseMotionListener have worked great for me.

Edit: and setting the JLabel's curser as noted by Max -- 1+ up-vote for him!

Comment: Now i have the impression that i don't know any thing about swing :/

Comment: @IManis: Not true. You just don't know *everything* about Swing -- and neither do I! I just learned some cool things from Max and Jakub (1+ to him too!).

Comment: I was searching for what this question asks and I found [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002633/create-event-by-clicking-at-the-jlabel) about the implementation suggested on this answer.